# typesetting in the style of Turing's famous "ON COMPUTABLE NUMBERS"

Tags: typography, document-classes

Maybe an unusual question but I love the typographical style of this text.

http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps210/Winter11/Papers/turing-1936.pdf

I am an art student writing a research paper. I would love to be able to present it in the style of Turing's famous text.

Is there a `\documentclass{}` that will approximate the style used in this paper.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: You need to sort out what font is needed.  That is the hardest part --- unless, that is, you need to typeset the exact same maths in the exact same way.  You could easily replicate headers with `fancyhdr`, footnotes with `footmisc`, and sectional divisions with `titlesec`; in fact, some of the more feature rich classes like `memoir` and `KOMA-Script` will get you pretty far along on their own.  Note however that TeX will do a much 'better' (read: tighter) job with interword spacing by default.

Comment: [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) can be used to identify fonts.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It seems to me that the font used is not Times. My guess is that, being the document scanned, the font properties are filled in the with default system font values (times for serif, helvetica for sans serif, courier for monospaced). I would follow Mars advice to identify the font...

Comment: beautiful tables :)

Comment: there are some features of which you should be aware.  math typography was the precinct of only a few specialists, and only a few fonts were suitable, since it was necessary to be able to distinguish every letter (latin (upright and italic), greek, fraktur, ...) *in isolation*.  particular care needed to be taken with the shape of the italic "v" so it wouldn't be confused with "nu", so the "w" was usually also given a rounded shape to blend with the "v".  (there's an example of "w" on the last page.)  no space for more details.  you have an interesting project.

Comment: @guillem yes, you're right. My previous comment can be misleading, so I'll delete it.

Comment: This is one of the many knock-offs of the Century family of typefaces. Currently available are New Century Schoolbook and Monotype's Century MT. Computer Modern, if memory serves, was based on a Century typeface, so CM math should harmonize. I think that somewhere on CTAN there is a version of New Century Schoolbook to be had. The match won't be exact, but you will capture the flavor of the original.

Comment: Ah one of my favourite papers. `:)`

Comment: @sgmoye Thnaks for your comment! And you're right; CTAN has a version of New Century Schoolbook through [fouriernc](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newcent/).

Comment: Thank you all for your generous and detailed responses. I'm really starting to love TeX!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can give you a starting point:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{examplexyz.bib}
@article{alonzo,
title={An Unsolvable Problem of Elementary Number Theory},
author={Alonzo Church},
journal={American Journal of Mathematics},
volume={58},
number={2},
month={April},
year={1936},
pages={345-363}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.27in,paperheight=9.69in,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[symbol*,bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addbibresource{examplexyz.bib}

\newpagestyle{mypstyle}{
  \sethead[\thepage][\scshape\Author][{[Aug, \number\day}]{\number\year]}{\scshape\Title}{\thepage}
  \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}
}
\pagestyle{mypstyle}

\DefineFNsymbols*{mystyle}{{$\dagger$}{$\ddagger$}\S\P\|%
*{**}{$\dagger\dagger$}{$\ddagger\ddagger$}}

\setfnsymbol{mystyle}

\newcommand\periodafter[1]{#1.}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\filcenter}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{\itshape\periodafter}

\title{On computable numbers, with an application to the  entscheidungsproblem}
\author{A. M. Turing}

\makeatletter
\def\Title{On computable numbers.}
\let\Author\@author
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule
  \kern2.6\p@}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\MakeUppercase{\@title}\par}%
    \vskip 1.7em%
    {\lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \textit{By}~\@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 0.8em%
    {\footnotesize\@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 0.5em%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Computing machines}
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
Test text\footfullcite{alonzo}
\lipsum[4]
The machine is to have the four $m$-configurations, ``$\mathfrak b$'', ``$\mathfrak c$'', ``$\mathfrak k$'', ``$\mathfrak e$'' and is capable of printing ``$0$'' and ``$1$''. The process of printing this $1$ will be called marking $\beta$ (or $S$) with $a$. 
\[ 
\lambda w \biggl[ \{W_\gamma\} \bigl(\bigl\{\{Q\}(W_\gamma)\bigr\} (w)\bigr)\biggr] 
\]
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}>{None}c*{2}{>{$}c<{$}}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Configuration} & 
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Behaviour} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\itshape $m$-config.} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\itshape symbols} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\itshape operations} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\itshape final $m$-config.} \\
\mathfrak b & & P0,R & \mathfrak c \\
\mathfrak c & & R & \mathfrak e \\
\mathfrak e & & P1,R & \mathfrak k \\
\mathfrak k & & R & \mathfrak b
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

An image of the resulting document:

[image]

#### Comments

- The [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package was used to produce the paper dimensions used in the article: `6.27inx9.69in`; the `centering` option was used to produce equal values for the margins in `twoside`.
- The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used to customise the format for section titles; a similar job can be done for other sectional units.
- The `pagestyles` option for `titlesec` was used to produce a pagestyle having headers as in the original documents; this could have also been done using [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).
- [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `\footfullcite` commands were used to produce the full citations as footnotes.
- I used the [`footmisc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package with the symbol option; this, together with the use of `\DefineFNsymbols` allows you to define the set of symbols that yu want to be applied to footnote markers.
- I redefined `\footnoterule` so that the rule separating text from footnotes spans the whole text width.
- I also redefined `\@maketitle` to emulate the style of the title information. Another option here, would be to use the [`titling`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package.
- I defined some auxiliary commands `\Title` and `\Author` to have the author and (part of the) title in the headers.
- In a comment to the question,  **sgmoye** identified the font as pertaining to the Century family of typefaces. According to the LaTeX Font Catalogue, the `fouriernc` package provides support for [`New Century Schoolbook for LaTeX`](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newcent/). The following uses this package; as
  sgmoye warns, "the matching to the original is not exact, but captures the flavour of the original".
- After a suggestion by **barbara beeton**, I added some elements from the original document (a bit of maths and one of the tables), to show the blend between text and math fonts. **barbara beeton** kindly provided the math expressions.

Comment: Gonzalo, You too get tired? I don't believe it ;-)

Comment: this does look nice, but it's not the same font.  the "e"s are all wrong.  the article from *proc. london math. society* was puclished in 1937, almost certainly with a monotype font.  the details of the letters that i checked are consistent with those of the font on which computer modern was based -- monotype modern series 8a -- although all the letters are consistently narrower than 8a.  if someone can find a monotype font catalog from that era (preferably a british/european version), identification should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes; the fonts are not the same; last night I misread the information from the menu "Properties" and that's why I ended up using the "dreadful" Times/Helvetic/Courier combo. In my updated answer I suggested `What the Font` (the Forum, since I used their on line application with no joy) to help identifying the precise font.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- a friend found this on line for me -- a scanned copy of the monotype font book, at (http://www.donblack.ca/Monotype/MonotypeSpecimenBook.pdf).  it's 700+ pages, so it takes a while to download.  monotype series 1A and 4A look promising (i'm printing those pages out to do some measuring); they're very like 8A (the model for computer modern) except that they're narrower.  (blessings on whoever allowed this invaluable book to be scanned!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton A jewel, indeed! Thanks for taking the time for this! Do you happen to know if any of those monotype fonts is (freely) available, to use with XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Gonzalo: I think you can get close enough with just the default TeX font.

Comment: @morbusg yes, it's closer to the original than what I had. Thank you!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- in a comment to the original question, sgmoye has identified the font as some variant of century, and suggests that new century schoolbook support might be available on ctan.  (the monotype A series fonts appear to be modeled on century, so this is not a surprise.  however, i think the width is a possible problem, because, as with modern 8A and computer modern, c.s. is relatively wide -- for easier comprehension by beginning readers.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Ah, I hadn't seen that comment. I've updated my answer with a version using `fouriernc` (which uses New Century Schoolbook). What do you think? To my untrained eye, this looks closer to the original than with CM, although it's not a perfect match. Should I leave just this version and remove the one using CM or should I left both?

Comment: @barbarabeeton perhaps the [TeX Gyre Schola](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgschola/) would be a better option? (Sorry to bother you).

Comment: @Gonzalo: I just tried; Schola is a lot heavier, and one thing to consider is maths; here's how it looks with CM maths: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/kMA36Gg.png) (The zero and one are in math mode.)

Comment: @morbusg Yes, it looks too heavy and doesn't blend well with CM maths. I'll then leave the example with `fouriernc`. Thank you!

Comment: @Gonzalo: No problem, and +1 for very nice answer. By the way, I noticed that [GUST is working on a Schola math font](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math).

Comment: @Gonzalo -- the more i think about it, the more i think this sample should have at least a few bits of math.  so here's my offering.  `The machine is to have the four $m$-configurations, \lduot$\mathfrak b$\rdquot, \ldquot$\mathfrak c$\rdquot, \ldquot$\mathfrak k$\rdquot, \ldquot$\mathfrak e$\rdquot and is capable of printing  \ldquot$0$\rdquot and \ldquot$1$\rdquot. The process of printing this $1$ will be called marking $\beta$ (or $S$) with $a$. \[ \lambda w \biggl[ \{W_\gamma\} \bigl(\bigl\{\{Q\}(W_\gamma)\bigr\} (w)\bigr)\biggr] \]` (pardon the "quotes"; markdown is tough on them.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you're absolutely right! Not including some maths in this kind of document is committing an injustice. I will add your excerpt, and perhaps some other of the original elements (a little table perhaps). Thanks, once again.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've added the math excerpt you kindly offered and also one of the tables from the original document. The result looks now great. Thanks you very much!

Comment: In the original, the footnote symbols are not superscripted. Is it possible to adjust this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have such a template. I see couple things that should be done when writing the article, and IMHO it is too much to be just a comment.

1. Notice that § (coded as `\S`) stands for "section" and §§ (coded as `\S\S`) stands for "sections", as was usual back then.
2. The quotation marks are badly-spaced, and they should be written as `` `{}` `` and `'{}'` or with the appropriate ligatures disabled (this is possible via `fontspec` in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX).
3. To simulate the effect of non-uniform letters, you can use `\usepackage[stretch=70]{microtype}`, which will allow the font to stretch and shrink from line to line, creating such an effect.